# How to perform search and replace in vim in reverse?

Tags: vim

I need to perform a search and replace regex in vim of the style:

```
s/search/replace/g
```

However, I need to do this in reverse, from the bottom of the text to the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you would want to do that (and your question has a strong XY problem smell to it) but you could reverse your text, do a normal substitution and revert your text back to its original order:

```
:g/^/m0
:%s/search/replace/g
:g/^/m0
```